# Hot to get gender of friends on facebook using OpenGraph Api?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to get all gender from all my friends on facebook using OpenGraph Api and Facebook SDK.

Step 1 : OpenGraph

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.0

and query: xxxxxxid/friends?fields=gender

but with or without Limit field I get only few result.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Is xxxxxxid you? If you take a random user id it may be that their friends gender is not available for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Facebook API v2.0, `/{user}/friends` will only return friends who already use your application.

`friends` endpoint will only return `id` and `name` (in v1.0 it also returned `installed` field, but not anymore as it's now restricted to app users only).

If still useful for you, you can get friends gender by calling `/{user}` on friend's IDs.

Cheers!

Edit: Removed user_birthday reference

Comment: thanks, my problem are API v2.0 , i will create a new  question

Answer (score 0):

Only id and name is available via /me/friends on v2 of the platform, and then only for other users of your app. But if they use the app, then you can ask them using `user_birthday`.